# Why view.layer.backgroundColor = randomColor won't animate the color change?

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, calayer

When I trying to set view.layer.backgroundColor, the color changes immediately without animation. 
But if I create a CALayer, add it as the sublayer of view.layer, and change the backgroundColor of that CALayer, I can see the implicit color change animation.
Can anyone explain why there is no animation when changing `view.layer.backgroundColor` ?

```
\\ add CALayer
self.colorLayer = [CALayer layer];
self.colorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
self.colorLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.colorLayer];

\\change the color somewhere else
CGFloat red = arc4random() / (CGFloat)INT_MAX;
CGFloat green = arc4random() / (CGFloat)INT_MAX;
CGFloat blue = arc4random() / (CGFloat)INT_MAX;
self.colorLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0].CGColor; // can animate
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0].CGColor; // won't animate
```

Comment: can u show the code of how u create the calayer and chnage its background color ?

Comment: edited, Thank you! @Mr.T

Comment: You're not actually telling it to animate though. You're just changing it.

Comment: CALayer background color is an animatable property, howver setting the background color in a normal way doesnt animate the change in background color. You need to use CABasicAnimation to make the color change with animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [*Core Animation Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW17):

> Because iOS views always have an underlying layer, the UIView class itself derives most of its data from the layer object directly. As a result, changes you make to the layer are automatically reflected by the view object as well. This behavior means that you can use either the Core Animation or UIView interfaces to make your changes.
>
> If you want to use Core Animation classes to initiate animations, you must issue all of your Core Animation calls from inside a view-based animation block. **The `UIView` class disables layer animations by default but reenables them inside animation blocks.** So any changes you make outside of an animation block are not animated.

(Emphasis added.)

Comment: Clearly I need to take more amphetamines if I want to type as fast as you do! :)

Comment: Copy 'n' paste for the win!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that this layer is the underlying layer *of a view*. There is no implicit layer animation for that layer. There is implicit layer animation only for (what we might call) secondary layers, i.e. sublayers that you add yourself.

Comment: For what the underlying layer is, see: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch16.html#_view_and_layer

Comment: For implicit layer animation, see: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_implicit_layer_animation And note the NOTE: "You cannot use implicit animation on the underlying layer of a UIView. You can animate a UIView’s underlying layer directly, but you must use explicit layer animation"